# Selecting specific ID from column names of a matrix based on a data frame column

Tags: r

I have a matrix and data frame like the ones below:

Matrix:

```
   A_96_apples_orange | B_92_apples_orange | A_83_bananas_green | B_83_bananas_green

A       5                      .....             ....                 ....
B       10                     ....              ....                 ....
C       8                      ....
D       ....                   ....              ....                 ....
```

Dataframe:

```
      Quartile  |   ID 
1        1        96_apples_orange
2        3        91_apples_red 
3        3        72_grapes_blue
```

Here are the steps I want to take:

1. remove the prefix "A_" and "B_" from the matrix column names to find and keep only the duplicated names (I have done this successfully).
2. select only the matrix column name that matches my df ID column
3. paste prefixes "A_" and "B_" back into the selected matrix column names.

the "..." represent numeric values in the matrix.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: plase share your matrix and dataframe with `dput(matrix_name)` and `dput(data.frame_name)`

Comment: Hi Guedes, I actually won't be able to share my actual df and matrix but I can fill in the matrix if that's more helpful?

Comment: You can share dummy/fake data, as long as it is reproducible. Always share data as code, never as images or formatted tables. You can generate a minimal fake dataset that reproduces your problem and share it with `dput`

Answer (score 0):

We can collapse the `df$ID` variable into a single pattern for the regex inside `grep` with `paste(sep = "|")`.

then subset the matrix as usual, but with the argument `drop = FALSE` to keep the dimensions attributes of the matrix.

**A small reprex:**

```
mtx <-structure(1:6, .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("A_96_apples_orange", 
"B_92_apples_orange", "A_83_bananas_green")))

mtx
     A_96_apples_orange B_92_apples_orange A_83_bananas_green
[1,]                  1                  3                  5
[2,]                  2                  4                  6

df<-data.frame(Quartile = c(1,3,3), ID = c('96_apples_orange', '91_apples_red', '72_grapes_blue'))

df

  Quartile               ID
1        1 96_apples_orange
2        3    91_apples_red
3        3   72_grapes_blue
```

**Answer**

```
mtx[,grep(paste(df$ID, collapse = '|'), colnames(mtx)), drop = FALSE]

     A_96_apples_orange
[1,]                  1
[2,]                  2
```